# JSON Serialize Enum to Integer

Tags: c#, json, enums

I have enum data type,

```
public enum RoundingType : int
{
         [Description("Normal")]
         [EnumMember(Value = "Normal")]
         Normal = 1,
         [Description("Round Up")]
         [EnumMember(Value = "Round Up")]
         Up = 2,
         [Description("Round Down")]
         [EnumMember(Value = "Round Down")]
         Down = 3
}
```

At this time I use the `JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))` attribute on each class property so that during the serialization process the data displayed is the enum item string. What if I want to do a custom serialization so that when I serialize an object to Json, especially for the enum data type, it produces an integer value as output? I will use this integer value to bind to the dropdown.

I've been browsing for this solution but haven't found an answer yet. Do you guys have any ideas/solutions. Or do I have to use each enum's string as the value in the dropdown? Or any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried removing the converter?

Comment: The question is unclear. You add that attribute because the *default* is to serialize as an int. You don't need anything custom. *Remove* the attribute. Did you configure the enum serialization globally perhaps, which means removing the attribute has no effect?

Comment: try int num=(int) RoundingType

Comment: @MahdiAnjam you haven't read the question I suspect. It asks about JSON serialization. Serializing to int is the default, because enums *are* numbers

Comment: @GuruStron, If I omit the serialization converter attribute it will produce an integer value, and I have to convert it on the client side view.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, At this time, the string values (Normal, Round Up, and Round Down) are displayed.

Comment: So you want two values on the frontend?

Comment: @Amigo yes, because you added the custom converter. Do you still get strings if you *remove* the attribute? Have you added the converter to the application's configuration perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, The serialization enum results in an integer value if I delete the attribute. And I need both integer values and string values.

Comment: That's not what you asked. Serialization means emitting a value in a single form. What you ask is how to emit an object with ID and label for an Enum, not one of the two possible forms. Post what you *really* want to generate. You can create your own custom converter that writes whatever you want instead of `Enum.ToString()`

Comment: @Amigo or do you want to change between forms based a flag like eg a query parameter? Why would you want that? You're forcing people to guess. Please add examples of what you really want to generate and when

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I use the JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter)) attribute on the enum property. So that when the system sends the serialization result of an object from the controller to the client side (JsonResult), the enum data is a string item. In the edit form, the enum data that I need is an integer for binding with the dropdown item (selected item). This is the problem.

Comment: And I have found the solution, that I shouldn't use attribute JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter)). If I need the string name of the enum data, I just need to add the JsonStringEnumConverter option for serialization, and the default serialization for enum data is integer. By the way thanks for the concern and help @Panagiotis Kanavos, I really appreciate your help. Sorry if I explained wrongly or couldn't explain my problem because I'm just learning programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))` attributes from class properties and control how enums are being serialized via SerializerOptions:

```
public static string ToJson<T>(this T o, bool enumAsString) 
{
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
    if (enumAsString) {
        options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    }

    return JsonSerializer.Serialize(o, options);
}
```

Comment: Can I use the extension in controller when return Json ?

Comment: Depending on how exactly do you return result from controller. `JsonResult` has got constructor with two parameters, second one is serializer options so instead of serializing data yourself you can just pass right options. Alternatively, returns `ContentResult` with ContentType = 'text/json' and Content = json serialized as in my answer.